# ios the "in-app purchase" check box in appID settings cannot edit

Tags: ios, push-notification, in-app-purchase

I enabled the push notification of a appID, and then I found the check box for in-app purchase is also checked. The screenshot is as follows:
[image]

The production provisioning profiles created by this appID writes that in-app purchase is enabled. 
However, my app does not have any in-app purchase functionality so I wondering if I did somthing wrong or this is normal? I am worried about that the app may be rejected because there is actually no in-app purchase in the app.

I heard about that there are some configurations need to be done before submit for review if the app has in-app purchase. is there any for push notification too?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. Your app is not going to reject for enabling in app purchase or push notification even though you don't implement those.

These are default services those are enabled while creating an application.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: My app does have push notification, do I need to do any extra configurations for it before submitting for review? I did not see any options for mantaining push notification information in itunes connect app management.

Comment: No you don't have to.